# ASP.Net Webforms - pages clientIdMode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.5

I am in the process of upgrading a legacy ASP.Net Website (Web Forms) from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5.  I recently noticed after the upgrade some ASP.Net controls were re-named from `ctl00_Content_dropDown1` to `ctl00$Content$dropDown1` in the HTML, breaking a lot of the client-side JavaScript.

How can I stop this change from occurring after the upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[docs.Microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770142) says that moving from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0 (or greater) causes this breaking change that changes the way that the `id` attribute for elements is generated.

In the web.config file, change the `<pages>` element, add the `clientIDMode` attribute to it like this:

```
<pages clientIDMode="AutoID" ...
```

This should continue making IDs in the way that it did before.

In addition to `AutoID`, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) lists several other useful options:

- AutoID - Auto-generate the segments with the underscore character
- Inherit - Inherit the mode from the parent container
- Predictable - Default value for a page in .NET 4.0 and up
- Static - ClientID is set to the value of the ID property

Visual Studio is supposed to set the `ClientIDMode` to `AutoID` when you upgrade from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5, however I don't think it works when you do not have a ASP.Net Web Project (.csproj) and instead all you have is a ASP.NET Website.